# Proof that there is no identity to integral operation on any set of functions

Tags: integration, functions

The statement is:
Let $f\in F, f:x\mapsto f(x)$ be a function($F$ contains sufficiently non-trivial functions). Then
$\not\exists I\in F$, so that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty If=f(0)$$
What I am implying: I found a statement on wikipedia, that there is no identity over space of functions with operation of convolution and therefore delta function is in fact distribution. I tried to prove this, but with no luck. Can it be proven?

Comment: It seems to me the claim is false if $(x\mapsto 0) \in F$ and $f(0) = 0$. I think perhaps you meant there is no $I$ that satisfies the equation for all $f$ in $F$ when $F$ contains sufficiently non-trivial functions, or some other variation on this claim. Where is this statement on Wikipedia? Perhaps it would give better context to this question.

Comment: What David said.  Certainly for a small enough space $F$ (say, finite-dimensional), there is such $I$.

Comment: yes, it is for non-trivial functions. It is hard to formulate, because in the text, it is not defined what function space it should be.